# Did I re-link TFS and SharePoint correctly?

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2013

This is TFS 2015 and is my first install (and usage) experience with both TFS and SP.

I installed SP first, of course, and during installation the Configuration Wizard prompted me for my initial Site Collection—I named it Development and selected the root directory for its location (e.g. http://server3/ and not http://server3/sites/).

But then after installing TFS something seemed a bit odd. There was a DefaultCollection, but it appeared as though it was some sort of 'child' collection under Development. I didn't think that was right, so I removed the whole thing. All that was left was the SP Central Admin portal (e.g. http://server3:333/).

Then I created a new Web Application in SP, specifying port 80. I created a new Site Collection, based on the TFS Project Portal template, this time calling it DefaultCollection in anticipation of the upcoming TFS re-link.

Then I set about re-linking TFS. Using the TFS Admin Console, I took these steps:

1. Under SharePoint Web Applications I used these values:

   a) Friendly Name: DefaultCollection

   b) Web Application URL: http://server3/

   c) Central Administration URL: http://server3:333/

   d) Default location: /
2. Under Extensions for SharePoint Products I created a new Access Grant, mapping http://server3:8080/tfs to http://server3/ and leaving the remaining optional fields blank.
3. Then finally, on the SharePoint Site tab of DefaultCollection under Team Project Collections, I selected DefaultCollection and set the Relative Path to /.

Screen shots from the TFS Admin Console are at the end.

So my question is—did I do all of this correctly? (I'm pretty sure I did it in the order indicated; feel free to correct me if my memory is a bit off.)

Everything verifies and I'm getting no error messages on either side, but all the same how would I go about making sure that all is working as it should? I suppose maybe create something in TFS and see if it automatically shows up in SP? How best to do that?

Side note: For the moment I'm still on VS13, so I can't create a new Team Project quite yet.

Does all of this look right, to those in the know? What's my best test to prove it?

---

[image: Add Web Application]
[image: Add Access Grant]
[image: Set Default Site Location]

Comment: It's worth noting that SharePoint integration isn't very useful or important. TFS 2015 has better, more customizable team dashboards than SharePoint. SharePoint is basically a document management system at this point, and you don't need to integrate it with TFS to use it for that.

Comment: @DanielMann: Gotcha, thanks. Sounds good to me. I imagine I'll find out whether I've done it right somewhere along the line...  either it'll work or it won't! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your setting, your DefaultCollection site location is http://server3/, you can access it to see whether you can open it. You may specify the Relative Path to the team project collection name, as if you have another team project collection, you can tell from the site location directly.

It's suggested you created a new team project with sharepoint site when you have VS 2015 installed, then check the team project site to see whether everything works as expected.

By the way, share our server setting for your reference, which is the normal configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I finally managed to get VS15 installed—my was *that* a beast!—and so I was able to create a New Team Project. A corresponding collection was created for me in SharePoint, so the integration must be working. Just as an extra safety check, where in TFS would I add/upload a document to verify that it indeed shows up in SharePoint as well?

Comment: I should note that there appears to be a bug in the *Edit Default Site Location* dialog. I deleted my original SharePoint DefaultCollection and created a new one on a non-default port, redoing all the links; the dialog then doesn't allow that port to be specified. A subsequent 'Failure connecting to the server' error occurs (I created a firewall rule). Are you able to reproduce this?

Comment: Under Team Explorer--Document, right click one folder, then you can upload document.

Comment: You can use the randomly generated port number, but Team Foundation Server has always used 17012 as the port for the SharePoint Products administration site. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd578615(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: "...then you can upload document." OK, thanks for that. I tried it; it works great. Mission accomplished. +1

Comment: "You can use the randomly generated port number..." Thanks, but that doesn't answer my question about the dialog. Are you able to reproduce what I'm describing? (I created my SharePoint DefaultCollection on port 81, as I'm soon going to need 80 for an unrelated application.)

Comment: If you specify a different port number than 80 when you create a Web application, you must include it as part of the address for Team Foundation Server to operate correctly.

Comment: I did and it does indeed work correctly. The integration has no problems; I was able to upload and verify the document as you suggested (thank you). What I'm referring to is the misbehavior of the Edit Default Site Location dialog that doesn't allow a port to be specified in the URL. Are you able to reproduce what I'm describing?

Comment: When you create web application to use a port number than 80 in Share Point Central Administration console, do you specify the URL of Web Application with port number?

Comment: Yes. And the URL containing the port number displays correctly on the SharePoint Site tab under the Team Project Collections node on the TFS Admin Console. The integration also functions perfectly. It's only the Edit Default Site Location dialog that won't allow a non-standard port to be entered in the URL. Give it a try, you'll see what I mean. Create a SharePoint collection on port 81 and link TFS to it. I've done it twice now, each time with the same (favorable) result. It's a bug in the dialog behaviors.